# The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

Tags: apt, upgrade

I am using Parrot Linux. I am trying to execute `sudo apt-get update` but I get this error at the end:

> ```
> E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
> ```

I tried to change the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99defaultrelease` from:

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

to:

```
APT::Default-Release "wheezy";
```

But I that only slightly changes the error:

> ```
> E: The value 'wheezy' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
> ```

Comment: command: [grep -rn "APT::Default-Release" /etc/apt] ,
result: 
[/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99defaultrelease:1:APT::Default-Release "stable"; –]

Comment: command: [ grep -ri stable /etc ] , I get:
/etc/apt/preferences.d/parrot-pinning:Pin: release o=vscode stable ,
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99defaultrelease:APT::Default-Release "stable"; ,
and more from sublime,java etc. that have not to do for my problem

Comment: command : [ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99defaultrelease ] , I get: APT::Default-Release "stable";

Comment: I have not .synaptic folder in root folder (not even hiden one). when I hit:
[ whereis synaptic ] , I get:
synaptic: /usr/sbin/synaptic /usr/share/synaptic /usr/share/man/man8/synaptic.8.gz

Comment: I had a similar issue and could solve it by changing "stable" to "oldstable", but I am using Stretch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was executing some commands that I shouldn't (because these commands should be executed if you had Debian Stable. So I just reinstalled Parrot.